# How to store the HttpClient get request values in 2d array- Angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6

I am making a get request to a server and need to store the response in a 2d array. I don't want to implement the interface and store value to it as the response structure will be changing from time to time and I don't want to modify the interface structure when it does.

Here is my code,
I created a common service for all components to make get and post request.

```
constructor( private http: HttpClient ) {    }
request(method: string, url: string, data?: any ) {
    return this.http.request(method, url, {body: data} )
}
```

From one of my components, I call this `request(method: string, service: string, data?: any)` method

In my `component.ts`

```
const user_list = this.my_service.request('get','my-url');
user_list.subscribe(
            response => { console.log(response); },
            (err) => this.error_handle.errorHandler(err),
        );
```

My Response looks like this

```
Response: [
 {
   "name": "anna",
   "age": "21",
   "createdAt": 1533673450284,
   "mobile": 9876543210,
   "friends": [
     {
       "name": "katy",
       "age": "21",
       "mobile": 9876543210
     }
   ],
   "updatedAt": 1533673450284,
   "timestamp": 1533673451240,
   "stats": {
     "friends": 10,
     "Active": 5,
   }
 }
]
```

Note: I will be having a lot of users list in my response and also a lot of friends list under each user list(As an example, I have given the simple structure)

As I said before, this structure will be changing a lot so I don't want to have a predefined array.

I need to store the list of users(including friends list) in a 2d array and access it later. Or is there any better way to implement this?

I tried to implement it like this but failed

```
data: string[][];
for (const obj of response ) {
this.icounter++;
    for (const key in obj ) {
             this.data[this.icounter][this.jcounter] = obj [key] ;
    this.jcounter++;
     }
 }
```

I am expecting an output like this, The user list should be like this.

```
[ ["anna"],["21"],["1533673450284"],["9876543210"],...],
  ["katy"],["22"],["1533673454820"],["9876543210"],...]
]
```

The friend's list of each user should be in a separate 2d array for each user.

```
[ ["katy"],["21"],["9876543210"],...],
  ["Friend2"], ["age"], ["Mobile no"]
]
```

I don't know whether is this a good practice, I couldn't think of any other solutions.

Comment: You have obviously put effort in your question, but in the end all the Angular/HTTP related stuff is somewhat irrelevant. What you're basically asking is: how do I convert this data array into an (unspecified) 2D data array. We can only guess as to what you want that result array to look like. Also, this community does not provide a code-writing service, and expects you to demonstrate the effort that you've already put into achieving your goal.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't show my work because If I add it then the question will be very long and the readers will feel bored.

Comment: What the difficulty you faced. You can assign response directly to any type array.

Comment: Well, the question is long because it contains a lot of irrelevant information. It can be rephrased as: "I have this format that I want to convert to this other format, and here's what I tried". Also, tagging your question with `javascript` (and optionally `typescript`) will make it visible to a lot more people.

Comment: @Indrakumara Can you please give me an example?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Yeah! you are correct. I will rectify that next time. Thanks for your time and advice.

Comment: For your current question, if you provide an example of what you want your output to look like, it will be a lot easier for people to answer.

Comment: @NavaneethSelvaraj what is your expected output